# How to organize data to send a post request to a API? laravel + vue-cli project

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, vue-cli

i'm writing a code using laravel as backend and vue-cli as frontend.
i've got a problem with the data to send to an API laravel restful controller. I get back as answer the err 500.
That's my saveEvent code:

```
saveEvent() {
        const staff = this.$store.getters.get_selected_staff.map(
            raw_staff => {
                return {
                    ...raw_staff,
                    icon: "mdi-drama-masks" ? "actor" : "technician",
                    percent:
                        raw_staff.percent == "full"
                            ? 1
                            : eval(raw_staff.percent),
                    allowance: parseInt(raw_staff.allowance),
                    daily: parseInt(raw_staff.daily)
                };
            }
        );

        const show = {
            ...this.$store.getters.get_tournee_show_detail
        };

        this.$http
            .post(
                "http://localhost:8080/api/tourneeDetail",
                `show=${JSON.stringify(show)}&staff=${JSON.stringify(
                    staff
                )}`
            )
            .then(response => {
                this.closeEvent();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("errore nella registrazione", error);
            });
        // );
    }
```

The datas goest straight to the controller and get manages in this way:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //

    dd($request->all());

    $tournee = new TourneeDetail;

    $show = json_decode($request->show, true);

    $staff = json_decode($request->staff, true);

    foreach ($show as $detail => $value){
        if($detail == "stage_id"){
            $tournee->stage_id = $value['id']; 
        }
        else{
            $tournee[$detail] = $value;
        }
    }

    $tournee->save();

    foreach ($staff as $row){
        $staff = new Staff;
        foreach ($row as $detail => $value){
            if ($detail!="icon" && $detail!="names" ){
                $staff[$detail] = $value;
            }
            
        }
        
        $staff->type = $row["icon"];
        $staff->tournee_detail_id = $tournee->id;
        
        $staff->save();

        foreach ($row["names"] as $id){
            $staff_person = new StaffPerson;

            $staff_person->person_id = $id;
            $staff_person->staff_id = $staff->id;

            $staff_person->save();
        }
    }

    return $tournee;
    
}
```

The problem is that i get the 500 error on the 1rst foreach. I put a dd to check the $request->all() and i noticed that the payload sent is correct but the preview is an empty array!
I dunno how to fix this problem..any help would be appreciated!

Thank you
Valerio

Comment: you are saying `dd($request->all());` is empty

Comment: Have you tried sending a request to just /api/tourneeDetail?

Comment: I didn't get your comments. What do you mean? I send a fake request like an object to tourneeDetail and the dd shows me those data,

Comment: yes @bhucho and I don't understand the reason why it's empty. I need help to try to understand why so

Comment: are your ports same as laravel has a port on 8000